# Comprehension of 有了...才

Tags: grammar

> 企业都在竞争市场，有了市场才有效益。

**My translation** : *Companies are in the markets and competing each other. Only if markets exist can is there profits*

I've parsed 有了市场才有效益 with

- 有了市场(There is markets)
- 才有效益(only there is profits)

Writing till here now I thought that 如果 or 要是 etc may able to be added just before 有了。

Namely the orig 2nd half sentence might be able to be converted as **如果(/要是)** 有了市场(**就**)才有效益

Is this my thought correct??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would translate it as:

> Companies are all in competitive markets, and **only** with a market **can they** be profitable.

For

> Namely the orig 2nd half sentence might be able to be converted as **如果(/要是)** 有了市场 **(就)** 才有效益

, "如果有了市场才有效益" may be more fluent in Chinese, while "如果…才…" here can be translated as "There will be profits **only if** market exists."

Answer (score 1):

Your translation is ungrammatical in English ("can is there"), but I think the idea is correct. The grammar of the second half is like [只有……才……](https://resources.allsetlearning.com/chinese/grammar/Expressing_%22only_if%22_with_%22zhiyou%22)

I would translate it as:

> Companies operate in competitive markets. Only in the markets can they become efficient.

I translated 效益 as "efficiency" because I think it makes more sense in the context of competitive markets, but I may be wrong.

Answer (score 1):

> 有了市场才有效益

Perhaps, the structure 因为...所以... fits for it, like 因为有了市场，所以才有效益。

Another example: 因为有你，（所以）生活才有意义。 = 有你生活才有意义。

Answer (score 0):

企业都在竞争(compete for)市场，有了(have)市场才有(then)效益。

The sentence indicates that "enterprises are always **competing for** market share, (because only) have a share of the market **then** there is profit."